# Replace a regular expression submatch using a function

Tags: regex, go

Let's say I have strings like

```
input := `bla bla b:foo="hop" blablabla b:bar="hu?"`
```

and I want to replace the parts between quotes in `b:foo="hop"` or `b:bar="hu?"` using a function.

It's easy to build a regular expression to get the match and submatch, for example

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`\bb:\w+="([^"]+)"`)
```

and then to call `ReplaceAllStringFunc` but the problem is that the callback receives the whole match and not the submatch :

```
fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
    // m is the whole match here. Damn.
}))
```

How can I replace the submatch ?

Right now, I haven't found a better solution than to decompose myself `m` inside the callback with a regex, and to rebuild the string after having processed the submatch.

I would have used an alternate approach with a positive look behind were they available in Go but that's not the case (and they shouldn't be necessary anyway).

What can I do here?

---

EDIT : here's my current solution that I would like to simplify :

```
func complexFunc(s string) string {
   return "dbvalue("+s+")" // this could be more complex
}
func main() {
        input := `bla bla b:foo="hop" blablabla b:bar="hu?"`
        r := regexp.MustCompile(`(\bb:\w+=")([^"]+)`)
        fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
                parts := r.FindStringSubmatch(m)
                return parts[1] + complexFunc(parts[2])
        }))
}
```

*[(playground link)](http://play.golang.org/p/I6Pg8OUeTj)*

What bothers me is that I have to apply the regex twice. This doesn't sound right.

Comment: If you believe this is a design mistake, feel free to [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list).

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't know if it's a design mistake. It doesn't look like a optimal design to me but I might miss a simple one-pass solution. If other people here comments on this, I might file a bug but I need opinions.

Comment: Filing a bug if you have a concern is almost certainly a good thing.

Comment: @FUZxxl I submitted an issue : http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5690

Comment: hey @dystroy any luck on this as of today? I saw the patch has been refused, but I am just starting with Go. So, not sure if things today are different?

Comment: @zanona I didn't see anything new

Comment: @dystroy thanks. Just making sure I understand, this would be the same as javascript’s `“hello world”.replace(/(\w+)\s(\w+)/, function(match, word1, word2) {…});` right?

Comment: @zanona I think so, and using a variadic function as parameter just like in js would indeed make it clean

Comment: Years later.. I thinking using `FindAllStringSubmatchIndex` and a byte buffer to replace the results may be most effective.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the OP created an issue for this, but as of this post, still isn't implemented https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5690

Fortunately, it looks like someone else on the web has provided their own function that does this https://gist.github.com/elliotchance/d419395aa776d632d897

```golang
func ReplaceAllStringSubmatchFunc(re *regexp.Regexp, str string, repl func([]string) string) string {
    result := ""
    lastIndex := 0

    for _, v := range re.FindAllSubmatchIndex([]byte(str), -1) {
        groups := []string{}
        for i := 0; i < len(v); i += 2 {
            groups = append(groups, str[v[i]:v[i+1]])
        }

        result += str[lastIndex:v[0]] + repl(groups)
        lastIndex = v[1]
    }

    return result + str[lastIndex:]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the code bellow, but it seems to do what you seem to want it to do:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "regexp"
)

func main() {
        input := `bla bla b:foo="hop" blablabla b:bar="hu?"`
        r := regexp.MustCompile(`\bb:\w+="([^"]+)"`)
        r2 := regexp.MustCompile(`"([^"]+)"`)
        fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
                return r2.ReplaceAllString(m, `"${2}whatever"`)
        }))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5dWD5y-IzF)

---

Output

```
bla bla b:foo="whatever" blablabla b:bar="whatever"
```

---

EDIT: Take II.

---

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "regexp"
)

func computedFrom(s string) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("computedFrom(%s)", s)
}

func main() {
        input := `bla bla b:foo="hop" blablabla b:bar="hu?"`
        r := regexp.MustCompile(`\bb:\w+="([^"]+)"`)
        r2 := regexp.MustCompile(`"([^"]+)"`)
        fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
                match := string(r2.Find([]byte(m)))
                return r2.ReplaceAllString(m, computedFrom(match))
        }))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2tqnOCtza3)

---

Output:

```
bla bla b:foo=computedFrom("hop") blablabla b:bar=computedFrom("hu?")
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to compute the replacement of the submatch with a complex function (taking this submatch as input), that's why I can't simply use ReplaceAllString inside. As for the elegance, I fear the right solution will be worse :(

Comment: +1 for an alternate solution but like mine this forces to use two regexes while technically the first one contains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    input := `bla bla b:foo="hop" blablabla b:bar="hu?"`
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\b(b:\w+)="([^"]+)"`)
    fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllString(input, "${1}=whatever"))
}
```